# Loading Skype4COM.dll from .net 4.0 as .net 3.5 or below

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, skype4com

I’ve been trying to use the Skype4COM.dll in my C# Windows Form project to allow it to send and receive SMS using Skype. Up to this point I notice that Skype4COM.dll will work really well whenever I load it from a project developed using the .net framework 3.5 but it will not work at all if I use the 4.0 framework on windows 7 and will work but missing a lot of functionalities in Windows XP.  The problem that I have is that it looks that down-grading my project to framework 3.5 will give me a lot of problems because my application is huge, and trying to isolate the functionalities in a new dll will not work because It gets loaded as framework 4.0 everytime. I tried creating a application.exe.config and application.dll.config using  but  it doesn’t work.
Any suggestions? Any help will be appreciated…
Thanks

Comment: Check if there is new version of Skype4Com.dll compatible with .net 4.0

Comment: Skype4COM.dll is a COM object for windows according to the docs. When using it as a COM object, the version of .Net should not make any difference. How are you including it in your project ?

Comment: I Download the last version I encountered and registred it. It didn't changed anything. Also, I added the Skype4COM.dll from the "Add reference" option showed while right clicking the references folder in the solution explorer

Comment: I think the library doesn't work when the version of the Net framework is 4.0.
I've tried compiling an example in framework 3.5 and it worked nice.